# Is using files and directories instead of a database for authenticating users a good option?

Tags: database, security, filesystems, authentication

I want to know, that if I save the username as a folder name, and then the hashed password in an encrypted file inside the folder for each user with other user data in that folder, is it better than having the information in a database.

I'm asking this question because I thought about the speed when there are too many users.
So my idea is, that in a database, when we query it for the username and the password, it goes through every row and checks if it matches or not.

But in the file system, the username is the folder name, we can use some file_exists(); function (in PHP) and check if the directory exists or not. If it does, then check for the password and authenticate the user, otherwise tell, no user exists with this username.

I want to know:

1. Without Considering Security, is this a better solution than a database, why/why not?
2. With Considering Security, what problems can it have?

Thanks...

Answer (score 3):

1. It's a worse solution than using a database. Because the DB solves all the tricky [ACID issues](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID) so that you don't have to reinvent the wheel.
2. It doesn't matter that much security-wise. With the DB solution, your application needs read/write access to the DB tables, and your code needs to make sure e.g. that user A cannot read or modify data for user B. Similarly if you do it with files, your application needs read/write access to the directory tree, and the application thus needs to do the necessary access checks (unless you can use something like suexec).

Also, the idea of querying for username in the DB being significantly slower than using something like file_exists() is not correct. The DB can use an index to look up an indexed column (say, username) quickly, and file_exists() requires the kernel to walk the path to check the file, which is about the same amount of work (depending slightly on how the DB implements indexes (typically B-tree's) vs. how the filesystem implements directory tree indexing).

Comment: Ok, Thanks for the answer... Now I understand, that how the Path Lookup works... So I think I should use the DB to save the user information. Thanks... :D